# php listing directory and sub-directories as hyper-links with option for new folder

Tags: php, list, recursion, directory

I am trying to list all folders within the WWW directory of my WAMPserver with the option to create a new folder for each 'group' of sub-directories as a list of hyperlinks.
I know the code below (see bottom of post) doesn't correspond to HTML standards at the moment, I shall add the header and footer after I have the code below functioning as intended.

Currently the following occurs as output of the script below (see bottom of post):

```
www
    applied
        images
        NEW FOLDER
        templates
        NEW FOLDER
    NEW FOLDER
    coob
        includes
        NEW FOLDER
    NEW FOLDER
NEW FOLDER
```

when I'd like the output to be in the format:

```
www
    applied
        images
        templates
        NEW FOLDER
    coob
        includes
        NEW FOLDER
    NEW FOLDER
NEW FOLDER
```

I understand to list the sub-directories within each directory found you require a recursive function. I have added the 'random' text `">/>N_F-H:L:A-T_T<\<"` into the array due to the fact that this contains multiple symbols disallowed within directory names across multiple operating systems. - this is the one occurrence that shouldn't be treated as a directory and display the `NEW FOLDER` hyperlink.
I don't understand why when you run this script - The `NEW FOLDER` item comes up for each item within the list of a sub-directory, rather than just once per group of sub-directories. Why is this and how can I achieve the desired output?

```
<style type="text/css">
  ul.dirlist, ul.dirlist li
  {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 1em;
  }
</style>
<?php
function ListFolder($path, $default_dir)
{
    $dircontents = scandir($path);
    $dircontents[] = ">/>N_F-H:L:A-T_T<\<";
    $dirref = str_replace($default_dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, "", $path);
    //Leave only the lastest folder name
    $dirpaths = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $path);
    $dirname = end($dirpaths);
    echo "<ul class='dirlist'>";
    echo "<li><a href=test.php?path=".$dirref.">".$dirname."</a>";
    foreach($dircontents as $key => $dir)
    {
        if($dir == ">/>N_F-H:L:A-T_T<\<")
        {
            echo "<li>NEW FOLDER</li>";
        }
        else
        {
            if($dir != "." AND $dir != "..")
            {
                if(is_dir($path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $dir))
                {
                    Test($path.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$dir, $default_dir);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //close list
    echo "</li>";
    echo "</ul>";
}

$www_dir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$www_dir_parts = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR , $www_dir);

if(in_array('www', $www_dir_parts))
{
    $wwwkey = array_search('www', $www_dir_parts);
}
elseif(in_array('htdocs', $www_dir_parts))
{
    $wwwkey = array_search('htdocs', $www_dir_parts);
}
else
{
    $cancel = 1;
    //do nothing
}
//if the script hasn't been canceled
if(! isset($cancel))
{
    $i = 0;
    //default_dir as nothing to begin with
    $default_dir = "";
    $default_dir_www = "";
    while($i <= $wwwkey)
    {
        //create path to absolute directory path of www
        $default_dir .= $www_dir_parts[$i] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
        //increment i
        $i++;
    }
    $i = 0;
    while($i <= ($wwwkey - 1))
    {
        //create path to absolute directory path of www
        $default_dir_www .= $www_dir_parts[$i] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
        //increment i
        $i++;
    }
    $default_dir_www = rtrim($default_dir_www, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
    $default_dir = rtrim($default_dir, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
}
ListFolder($default_dir, $default_dir_www);
?>
```

Comment: I'm quite confused sir.. Why not using a directory iterator instead and building the hyper-links from the array? http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php

Comment: I'd like to add a hyperlink with `NEW FOLDER` to each group of directories and didn't know if that were possible with the directoryiterator class.

Answer (score 0):

Try below function instead

```
function ListFolder($path, $default_dir){
    $dircontents = scandir($path);
    $dirref = str_replace($default_dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, "", $path);
    $havesub = false;
    echo "<ul class='dirlist'>";
    foreach($dircontents as $key => $dir)
    {
        if($dir != "." AND $dir != "..")
        {
            if(is_dir($path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $dir))
            {
               echo "<li><a href=test.php?path=".$dirref.">".$dir."</a>";
               ListFolder($path.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$dir, $default_dir);
               echo "</li>";
               $havesub = true;
            }
        }
     }
    echo ($havesub) ? "<li>NEW FOLDER</li>" : '';
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

Comment: This lists the `NEW FOLDER` once at the very end of the list for only the top-most directory - unfortunately I need the link to exist within each group of sub-directories as in the example in the question.

Comment: The list on the left is what the function you have generated returns. The list on the right is what I am after. http://someimage.com/E64bxFJ

Comment: I don't know if you saw that i have edit the function

Comment: I have seen that you have, I am using the code currently in the code box above - it displays the contents as in the picture hyperlinked above.